# Earth Wind and Fire - why isn't water included?

Tags: bands, names, funk, soul

The traditional list of the primary elements is earth, wind, fire, and water.  The funk-soul band *Earth, Wind, and Fire* neglects the element of water.  Has the band ever explained why they left water out of the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is apparently attributed to band leader Maurice White's interest in astrology. I read this in an American magazine interview that Maurice White gave many years ago -- probably in the late 1980s. But I cannot quote the source.

Maurice White said that his astrological sign, based on his birth date, is Saggitarius, and that Saggitarius is associated with three of the four astrological elements, and water was not one of them.

This is detailed in the [Wikipedia article on the band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth,_Wind_%26_Fire#Formation_and_early_years_.281971.E2.80.931973.29):

> Maurice's astrological sign, Sagittarius, has a primary elemental
>   quality of Fire and seasonal qualities of Earth and Air, according to
>   classical triplicities. (Sagittarius in the northern hemisphere occurs
>   in the autumn, whose element is earth, and in the southern hemisphere,
>   it is spring, whose element is air. Hence the omission of Water, the
>   fourth classical element.)